# How to use data from stored procedure into second procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

The last few months I learned so much thanks to all the topics on the forum, thanks to everybody taking the effort answering them. They helped me to create my procedures but now I'm stuck.
And related topics haven't given me a solution so far.

Also looked at this page: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

**Let me explain the situation:**

I have created two procedures they work perfectly. They work with temperary tables.

Below I have written out as specific as possible (I hope). If further information is needed I can give this of course.

**The two procedures:**

1 - Calculations of costs made by own drivers, trucks, fuel consumption **>** **named CostOM**

2 - Calculations of revenue and costs on the trip (Revenue of orders, Haulage cost, toll cost etc.) **>** **named Trip_margin**

What I need to add to the second procedure (Trip_margin) is the calculated amount from  the first procedure (CostOM) that is in a column named 'CostOwnMat' (which stands for cost of own material).

Both procedures use the same primary key structure and that is the tripnumber.

They only difference is that procedure 1 can have the same tripnumber multiple times because a trip can be done be 2 or more drivers.

So I need the total sum of the 'CostOwnMat' and return this in the second procedure in a new column named 'total_cost_OM'.

When I have that then I have al the revenue, costs etc. on the trip needed to calculate the margin made on the trip.

**I think below is the direction of the solution but how to apply this?**

•   Table variables (DECLARE @t TABLE) are visible only to the connection that creates it, and are deleted when the batch or stored procedure ends.

•   Local temporary tables (CREATE TABLE #t) are visible only to the connection that creates it, and are deleted when the connection is closed.

•   Global temporary tables (CREATE TABLE ##t) are visible to everyone, and are deleted when all connections that have referenced them have closed.

•   Tempdb permanent tables (USE tempdb CREATE TABLE t) are visible to everyone, and are deleted when the server is restarted.

Comment: If you call one stored procedure from another, you can use a local temporary table, and its data will be visible in the called stored procedure. The only downside to this is that in the called procedure, you should make shoure the temp table exists.

Comment: Hi Jeremy when reading your comment I began thinking I had done this in a test already. Only cause off an error I thought I had to find another solution. So I tried it again, simplified and that worked. So now I did it for the SP in the question as well. Thanks your answer gave me a direction to follow. Regards Arno

Answer (score 0):

You can go with second solutions, Local temp table.

However going with this solutions, you need to take care when concurrent user is using same procedure in live application.

To do so first you need create temp table with unique name as per process, as like below:

```
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #tmpTable' + CAST(@@SPID AS VARCHAR) + ' 
(fld1 INT NULL) ');
```

Second thing is the existence of table when you need to use in second/another procedure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpTable') 
BEGIN
     -- your code
END
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, at this point I did some experimenting and I got it to run as I want it to. I tested in with a simpler SP. That worked so I did the same in the question. I used the Global temp like, create table ##CostEM_tb
(col1, col2, .......). It does the trick. I think I understand what you are warning about. But I don't think this will be an issue. The procedure is gong to be used for a automatic report. Regards, Arno